# Performing multi-cloud (AWS, Azure, GCP ) provisioning using ansible

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, ansible, google-cloud-platform

Best practices to perform multi cloud using ansible

Comment: What is the question? Request for external materials? Then it is out of topic.

Comment: I am just asking the best practices. What do you mean by "what is the question". I am just explaining my perspective of multi-cloud.

Comment: This is a broad and opinion-soliciting question - there is no "right" answer to this. Just opinions and discussion. It's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice, I would implement **three** separate playbooks and **three** different inventories to keep things simple. You could put together some logic to do conditionals based on the inventory and cloud provider be used, ***but why would you need to***?

I would then create separate roles for implementing the required resources, (from an AWS perspective) create_vpc (may include dhcp options and IGW), create_routes (and route tables), create_NACLs, create_subnets,  create security_groups, launch_asg(includes launch configuration), create_nat_gateway, create_nat_instance, create_elb, get_subnet_ids, get_vpc_id. The reason for creating the separate roles would to allow for flexibility in implementing resources and reuse of code.

You could easily write everything as the one playbook, and I would even recommend doing this initially to see how things work (getting familiar with ansible modules), then turn it into roles to allow for code reuse.

Include a shared variable file, (include_vars) to implement the various subnets and load balancers across the different cloud providers. This would result in three of the same environments implemented in each cloud provider.

I'm looking to implement this as a home project to learn about the differences between the different vendor offerings, based on my AWS knowledge.

Comment: Any updates on your home project for the multi cloud ?

Comment: nothing yet, will scratch something out this month though.